# Calculating $\int_Af$

Tags: calculus

Here's the problem:

Let $A=\{{(x,y) : 0 \le x + y \le 1,0 \le x + 3y \le 3}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $

and let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x+y} $. Compute $ \int_A f$.

So, here is what I have done so far:

$$u = x+y$$

$$v = x + 3y$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix} = T\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ $$g = T^{-1}$$ $$D_g = T^{-1}$$

Then, a three step process to continue:

$$det D_g = detT^{-1} = \frac{1}{detT} = \frac12$$

$$ (u,v): \{ (u,v): 0 \le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le 3 \} $$

$$ (u,v): \sqrt{u} $$

Then, I changed the variables and continued to solve:

$$ \int_Af = \int_0^1 du \int_0^3 \sqrt{u} \cdot \frac12dv $$

$$ = \frac32 \cdot \int_0^1 \sqrt{u} \cdot du $$

After this point, I am uncertain on how to proceed with the problem. Can someone show me how to reach the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{d}{du}\left(\dfrac{2u^{3/2}}{3}\right) = \sqrt{u}$

Comment: Does that mean it reduces into $\frac23$, and the answer would be simply 1?